# How close do you have to be to someone to have a Room Match with them in Pokemon Duel?

Tags: pokemon-duel

In Pokemon Duel, when I try to go into the Room Match module, I sometimes get a message telling me that the game could not read my GPS location.

In Version 3.0.6 for Android, the current version as of April 15, 2017, the message is:

> Your location could not be established. Please check your device's GPS settings and ensure they are set to ON.

How does location factor into Room Matches? Is there a maximum distance that you can be from someone before you are unable to have a Room Match with them? Considering that I am almost always able to find at least a dozen other available players ready to duel, it would seem that the requirement for physical proximity is rather loose, if it even exists at all.

Comment: Given that I've had opponents from the other side of the planet, I doubt there is a maximum distance.

Answer (score 1):

To join a Room Match, you need to know the room number and also the room code(if there is one). It doesn't depend on distance. You can even join a room match with someone on the other side of the planet.

Comment: If this is the case, why does the game want GPS?

Comment: @TylerH this question is not about Pokemon GO.

Comment: @RobertColumbia d'oh...